# Database exception while displaying Chatlist in Android Kotlin Chat app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have been developing a chatting app in Android using Kotlin and Firebase. Registering, searching and sending message to a user, all of this has been successful. But I'm unable to generate a chatlist which is a list of the recent chats of the user. The user can tap on it to access that particular chat, just like any other chatting app.

The user is stored in a User model and the data is registered in the database in that same format.

I am able to display the profile picture of the user using the addValueEventListener method but when the similar method is invoked for the chatlist, it throws an error - 
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type kushwaha.samir.boop.models.User

This is the code where the error occurs -

```
val user = snapshot.getValue<User>(User::class.java!!)
```

present in the function - chatList()

[Database view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKHUa.png)

MainActivityChat code >

```
class MainActivityChat : Fragment() {
    lateinit var profile_image: CircleImageView

    lateinit var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser
    lateinit var reference: DatabaseReference
    lateinit var referenceusers: DatabaseReference
    lateinit var referenceuserschats: DatabaseReference
    lateinit var referencechatlist: DatabaseReference


    var root: View? = null
    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    lateinit var fragment: Fragment

    var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null

    var userAdapter: UserAdapter? = null
    var mUsers: MutableList<User>? = null

    var fuser: FirebaseUser?=null

    private var usersList: MutableList<Chatlist>? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mainchat, container, false)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!

        val uid = firebaseUser.uid

        val floatingActionButton = root!!.findViewById(R.id.searchPerson) as FloatingActionButton

        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(activity, SearchActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!

        usersList = ArrayList()



        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist").child(fuser!!.uid)
        referencechatlist = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist").child(fuser!!.uid)


        profile_image = root!!.findViewById(R.id.profile_image)


        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").child(uid)
            .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    val user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)
                    //   usernamedisplay.text = user!!.username
                    if (user!!.profileImageUrl == "default") {
                        profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        Log.d(ProfileFragment.TAG, "No image retrieved/found")
                    } else {
                        //change this
                        context?.let { Glide.with(it).load(user.profileImageUrl).into(profile_image) }!!
                        Log.d(ProfileFragment.TAG, "Image set")
                    }
                }

                override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {

                }
            })

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats")
        reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                var unread = 0
                for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val chat = snapshot.getValue<Chat>(Chat::class.java!!)
                    if (chat!!.receiver == firebaseUser!!.uid && !chat!!.isIsseen!!) {
                        unread++
                    }
                }

                reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist").child(fuser!!.uid)
                reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        usersList!!.clear()
                        for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                            val chatlist = snapshot.getValue<Chatlist>(Chatlist::class.java!!)
                            usersList!!.add(chatlist!!)
                        }

                        chatList()
                    }

                    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {

                    }
                })



            }
            })

        updateToken(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().token)


        return root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        recyclerView = view!!.findViewById(R.id.recycler_viewmain)
        recyclerView!!.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    }

    private fun updateToken(token: String?) {
        val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens")
        val token1 = Token(token!!)
        reference.child(fuser!!.uid).setValue(token1)
    }

    private fun chatList() {
        mUsers = ArrayList()
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")

        reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                mUsers!!.clear()
                for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    **val user = snapshot.getValue<User>(User::class.java!!)**
                    for (chatlist in usersList!!) {
                        if (user!!.id == chatlist.id) {
                            mUsers!!.add(user)
                        }
                    }
                }
                userAdapter = UserAdapter(context!!, mUsers!!, true)
                recyclerView!!.adapter = userAdapter
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })

    }


    private fun status(status: String) {
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser!!.uid)

        val hashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
        hashMap["status"] = status

        reference.updateChildren(hashMap)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        status("online")
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        status("offline")
    }

    companion object {
        val TAG = "MainActivityChat"
    }
}
```

User Model

```
class User {

  var id: String? = null
  var phoneno: String? = null
  var profileImageUrl: String? = null
  var search: String? = null
  var status: String? = null
  var username: String? = null

  constructor(id: String, phoneno: String, profileImageUrl: String, search: String, status: String, username: String) {
    this.id = id
    this.phoneno = phoneno
    this.profileImageUrl = profileImageUrl
    this.search = search
    this.status = status
    this.username = username
  }

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

Chatlist model

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
class Chatlist(val id: String):
    Parcelable {
    constructor() : this("")
}
```

Logcat

```
2019-03-02 22:20:52.446 20562-20562/kushwaha.samir.boop E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: kushwaha.samir.boop, PID: 20562
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type kushwaha.samir.boop.models.User
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:423)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:214)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:212)
        at kushwaha.samir.boop.MainActivityChat$chatList$1.onDataChange(MainActivityChat.kt:187)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace, which tells you which method and which line exactly throws the exception? This make finding the error much faster.

Comment: @Meier yes! I've edited the question to add the logcat

Comment: Can you mark the line MainActivityChat.kt:187 ?
Because this is where the exception is happen accorind to the stack trace.

Comment: @Meier sorry for that
I've updated the question with the line

Comment: @Sam If you are simply trying to log the `snapshot` object without casting it to `User` class, what is the result?

Comment: @AlexMamo when I log the snapchat variable i.e. Log.d(TAG,"$snapshot")
The output is
DataSnapshot { key = status, value = offline }

Comment: @AlexMamo for some reason, no value was being sent to the snapshot
I fixed that and now the output is 
DataSnapshot { key = x0E4iYJ4hrVNaoEZjnl0ChwqlKY2, value = {status=online} }

So yes, data is surely received

Comment: Its even more weirder
Profile pic and name is retrieved, so data is surely retrievable
But for the snapshot output,
This is the logcat

2019-03-03 17:05:58.561 24254-24254/kushwaha.samir.boop D/MainActivityChat: DataSnapshot { key = Z9I9NjRthMUlPe5QfhLvzHWogzY2, value = {search=samir kushwaha, id=Z9I9NjRthMUlPe5QfhLvzHWogzY2, profileImageUrl=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/boop-db1.appspot.com/o/images%2F05dda862-b006-4468-a0e4-b3bd42fbd437?alt=media&token=01a0cb94-486d-4919-965a-eda1bd25f073, phoneno=+918169207279, status=online, username=Samir Kushwaha} }

Comment: /MainActivityChat: DataSnapshot { key = status, value = offline }
AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: kushwaha.samir.boop, PID: 24254
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type kushwaha.samir.boop.models.User
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:423)
        at    at kushwaha.samir.boop.MainActivityChat$chatList$1.onDataChange(MainActivityChat.kt:189)

Comment: This is the logcat covered in 2 comments
Here,
You can see that there is value in the first datasnapshot at .561

But at .562, it changes to blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, you say that when you try to log the content of your `snapshot` object you get:

```
{ key = status, value = offline }
```

Which obviously means that you are using a wrong reference. So you get that result because you are getting a reference in database for the `status` property which of type String and that's why you get that error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type kushwaha.samir.boop.models.User

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {}
```

to

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
val usersRef = rootRef.child("Users")
usersRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {}
```

Comment: Yep this code too has the same output as above,
DataSnapshot has value first, but changes to status afterwards :/

Comment: Actually no
the error is still same as above.
The issue was of that error which was coming and its still persistent.
I dont think creating a new question would help solve the error in this case.

Comment: I don't understand how that erroris still displayed since you said in a previous comment that the error is gone.

Comment: Thats what
I have posted the logcat na
See, DataSnapshot is initialized but in the second line, it gets initialized to status

Comment: If you try to log the user object what's the result?

Comment: This is the output


2019-03-03 18:41:00.813 28886-28886/? D/MainActivityChat: DataSnapshot { key = Z9I9NjRthMUlPe5QfhLvzHWogzY2, value = {search=samir kushwaha, id=Z9I9NjRthMUlPe5QfhLvzHWogzY2, profileImageUrl=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/boop-db1.appspot.com/o/images%2F05dda862-b006-4468-a0e4-b3bd42fbd437?alt=media&token=01a0cb94-486d-4919-965a-eda1bd25f073, phoneno=+918169207279, status=online, username=Samir Kushwaha} }

|2019-03-03 18:41:00.814 28886-28886/? D/MainActivityChat: kushwaha.samir.boop.models.User@110b24b

Comment: So it's working, you have the desired user object, right? Is it displayed in the RecyclerView?

Comment: Yep value is passed in the user object but I still get that error and the app crashes immediately.

Comment: Hey Man!
Thanks ya! <3
I was able to resolve it
turns out, there was a status key that was present in the database, due to which the app was crashing because the snapshot was trying to interpret the usage of that key
I just deleted it and the app is working now
Thanks bro :)